# alternative to single quote in MSSQL query

Tags: sql-server

My question may be silly.

I have an application that does not like single quotes.
I want to execute SQL query from that application.
When I form my SQL query, I cannot use single quotes. 
I am looking for alternative way for single quotes.
I am on MicroSoft SQL 2012.

Example, my SQL is like this,

```
SELECT name 
FROM People 
WHERE peopleId = '123'
```

However I want to write this without single quotes,
Something like below I was trying,

```
SELECT name 
FROM People 
WHERE peopleId = CHAR(39)123CHAR(39)
```

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean "your application does not like single quotes"?  What behavior are you experiencing?  I'm guessing that `peopleId` is of type `int` in which case quotes are not needed.  Depending on how you're actually executing the query, quotes need to be escaped like so.  'I''m now able to escape single quotes'  basically use a second ' to escape a '

Comment: Most likely, you're flirting with a bad idea.  Please describe your problem with more detail.  What is your data (examples) and what is your application code base.

Comment: Yes, I am flirting with a bad idea and I understand that. I am looking for a temporary solution until the application(product) defect is fixed, which is not in my hand. I tried this now.  SELECT name 
FROM People 
WHERE peopleId =CHAR(39)+CHAR(49)+CHAR(50)+CHAR(51)+CHAR(39)

Comment: Try to use parameters

Comment: What language are you using, in your application, to call the query?  Can you add that code?

Answer (score 1):

If it accepts double quotes...

`SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx

When `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is `ON`, identifiers can be delimited by double quotation marks, and literals must be delimited by single quotation marks. When SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is OFF, identifiers cannot be quoted and must follow all Transact-SQL rules for identifiers. For more information, see Database Identifiers. Literals can be delimited by either single or double quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

If your PeopleID or filter value is initially a numeric value you can do this.  If it is not numeric I don't know.

```
SELECT name 
FROM People 
WHERE peopleId = CAST(123 AS VARCHAR(25))
```